# How to upload file using jquery ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, file-upload

I have  a file uploading system using jquery's `formdata`
the thing goes like this --->

**HTML**

```
<form id="upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"   action="resource/php/upload.php">
    <input style="display:none;" type="file" id="upload" multiple>  
    </form>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#upload').change(function(e){

var formdata = new FormData(),file;
$('#ajax-loader').show();   //simple gif loader
    for(var i=0;i<this.files.length;i++){
        file = this.files[i];
            var ftype = file.type;
                formdata.append("files[]", file);           

    }
    if (formdata) { 
            $.ajax({
                url: "resource/php/upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                dataType : 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(data) {
                             $('#ajax-loader').hide();
                            //appends the currently uploaded images in  a div
                             }
                });
 }
});
```

**PHP**

```
//does lot of stuff
// echo's out 2 arrays in json format which is used in appending images as stated earlier^
echo json_encode(array("images"=>$db_image_id,"src"=>$db_image_src));
```

Now my question is when i am choosing files to upload it automatically using `#upload` an `#ajax-loader` is shown  and hidden when files are uploaded. But i want to show a progress bar in `percentage` and `ETA(time left)` replacing the simple `$('#ajax-loader')` . However I ***googled*** and was able to do that using `ajax-form` a jQuery Plugin.   But i want to do in more real terms i dont want to use any ***PLUGINS***. How will i do that ?

And one more question is whether using the `#upload-form` is that necesssary ?

Comment: I can appreciate wanting to learn how to do something without a plugin. If you have already found a plugin that does exactly what you want it to do,  a great way to learn is to dissect that plugin. Usually if you visit the plugin 's website or github you can find the source code complete with comments - and see exactly how they do it.

Comment: actually it does not exactly does what i want ! @Ethan can u help me?

Comment: Im actually boarding a cruise right now (I know,  what is wrong with me that I'm on SO on the way to Bermuda?), you should take a look at the html5 progress element - it may be the simplest way to accomplish your goal.  Use js to update the "value" property and style as you see fit.  Perhaps someone on land can lay it out for you in a complete answer?

Comment: can u show how html5 `progress` event works ? coz its not working for me! but i have xhr2 in my browser! @Ethan

Comment: You can use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: you may need to write your custom xhr callback to show progress event

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custome xhr function to achieve tracking of progress of file uploads

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "resource/php/upload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                dataType : 'json',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
               //@custome xhr
                xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
                   myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                   if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                       myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction,  false); // for handling the progress of the upload
                   }
                   return myXhr;
                },
               //@custome xhr end
                success: function(data) {
                             $('#ajax-loader').hide();
                            //appends the currently uploaded images in  a div
                             }
                });
```

See the comment @custome xhr in above code And add a function to update progress bar

```
function updateProgress(evt) {
    console.log('updateProgress');
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            console.log(percentComplete);
    } else {
            // Unable to compute progress information since the total size is unknown
            console.log('unable to complete');
    }
}
```

Ref:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest